# Getting Column headers into CSV while using camel Routing

Tags: apache-camel

I have a requirement where in i have to get data from the table including column names and save it to CSV. I have coded like the below to get only the data from table not column headers. Can someone help me with this

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("restlet:http://localhost:8583/.....")
    .setBody(simple("select * from userDetails"))
    .to("jdbc:dataSource")
    .marshal()
    .csv()
    .to("file://C:/test.csv");
}
```

Appreciate your help...

Answer (score 1):

The column names would be available to you in the exchange after the `to("jdbc:dataSource")` statement in the header-**CamelJdbcColumnNames**.

So, basically the solution would be close to this:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("restlet:http://localhost:8583/.....")
    .setBody(simple("select * from userDetails"))
    .to("jdbc:dataSource")
    .to("direct:setColumnNames")
    .split(body())
    .marshal().csv()
    .to("file://C:/test.csv");

    from("direct:setColumnNames")
    .getHeader("CamelJdbcColumnNames")
    .marshal().csv()
    .to("file://C:/test.csv");
}
```

I'd suggest you write a custom processor for yourself that would solve your cause as well.